# Paypal Magento integration

Tags: magento, paypal, payment

I've set the integration up in magento and it connects to paypal fine. The problem is, that it only allows the customer to pay using their paypal account when directed through to paypal. Ideally what I want is to give the user the option to pay with credit or debit card or paypal. I have had a look in my paypal account and I think I need to grant API access but it is asking for a third party API username, I assume this is magento but where can I find the Magento API username? This is driving me nuts! Any help woulkd be appreciated please.

Comment: You may try to ask on this site too -> http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you're using PayPal Express Checkout in Magento then it comes down to adjusting a couple of parameters in the SetExpressCheckout request that gets sent to PayPal.  I haven't looked at Magento in awhile, though, and I don't remember if the settings in the admin panel give you options to force that like you could if you edit the request directly.  Are you familiar with building Magento extensions?

Answer (score 0):

Things that hinder guest checkout.
- if it's Express Checkout 
go to your payment method (express checkout); advanced settings| Enabled Guest Checkout and click save config; top right corner

other instances may be:
1. The paypal account is not a business account
2. The paypal account does not have financials confirmed to the account
3. the account is not verified; see #2 
4. You have guest checkout turned off in the paypal account under:profile / selling tools / website preferences / paypal account optional - toggle to 'ON'; scroll down and save
5. As Andrew mentioned; if you have access to the Mage core files for PayPal, can inject SOLUTIONTYPE=SOLE
6. Note ** if someone has checkouted with paypal on another site, the guest checkout option will go away because it's tied to an session ID via the browser which can be cleared by clearing cache